# I try to use OrientDB in distributed mode. How can I configure on which nodes will be located a specific database?

Tags: orientdb

For example: I have three nodes in the same cluster ("node1","node2" and "node3"). These nodes are identical in configuration files hazelcast.xml. I want that the database "DB_1" was placed only on the first and on the second node. And database "DB_2" was placed only on the second and the third node.

I modifed the file "default-distributed-db-config.json" on the first and on the second node:

```
{
  "autoDeploy": true,
  "hotAlignment": false,
  "executionMode": "undefined",
  "readQuorum": 1,
  "writeQuorum": 2,
  "failureAvailableNodesLessQuorum": false,
  "readYourWrites": true,
  "servers": {
    "*": "master"
  },
  "clusters": {
    "internal": {
    },
    "index": {
    },
    "*": {
      "servers": ["node1","node2"]
    }
  }
}
```

I modifed the file "default-distributed-db-config.json" on the third node:

```
{
  "autoDeploy": true,
  "hotAlignment": false,
  "executionMode": "undefined",
  "readQuorum": 1,
  "writeQuorum": 2,
  "failureAvailableNodesLessQuorum": false,
  "readYourWrites": true,
  "servers": {
    "*": "master"
  },
  "clusters": {
    "internal": {
    },
    "index": {
    },
    "*": {
      "servers": ["node3"]
    }
  }
}
```

I modifed the file "distributed-config.json" in the database directory "DB_1" on the first and second node.
I removed from it all:

```
<NEW_NODE>
```

and  wrote everywhere the only names of the first and second nodes:

```
"*":{"@type":"d","@version":0,"servers":["node1","node2"]},"orole_node2":{"@type":"d","@version":0,"servers":["node2","node1"]},"e_node2":{"@type":"d","@version":0,"servers":["node2","node1"]},"ouser_node2":{"@type":"d","@version":0,"servers":["node2","node1"]},"oschedule_node2":{"@type":"d","@version":0,"servers":["node2","node1"]},"orids_node2":{"@type":"d","@version":0,"servers":["node2","node1"]},"v_node2":{"@type":"d","@version":0,"servers":["node2","node1"]},"ofunction_node2":{"@type":"d","@version":0,"servers":["node2","node1"]}}
```

But nonetheless if start the third node, then for database "DB_1" will run replicating  in the third node too.

(OrientDB v2.1.13)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible, every node of the same cluster has to be synchronized with the others.